# 1/2 is the probability that a fish being caught is a perch. What is the probability that we have 4 fish in total when 2 perch have just been caught?

Tags: probability, expected-value

> $\frac{1}{2}$ is the probability of the fish being caught as a perch. What is the probability that we have $4$ fish in total when $2$ perch have just been caught?

I'm not sure, but I think the answer is $\frac{3}{16}$. But I don't know how to do it. Also, what should I do to become better at this kind of problems? Expected value problems, in particular. As a side note, I'm asking how to see the key intuition of this type of problems.
Thanks in advance.

Comment: Which part of the world are you residing, there is no word called catched, it is caught

Comment: Sorry, I will fix it. *Fixed.

Comment: No problem, if English is not your native language, such things happen, You could be a good mathematics student even if your english is not that of a native speaker!!

Comment: Do you stop fishing immediately after catching your second perch?

Comment: The faulty conjugation of English irregular verbs is not an issue for me. I'm wondering why there is no information here showing what you have tried.

Comment: Sorry, I was busy with stuff going on. To be honest, I should've tried a little bit more before posting it here. I guess I was kind of "depressed/tired" and asked it here right away when I wasn't able to solve at the first glance. If you check my other questions, I've always included my solution/rather what I think. For future questions, I'll invest some time and then ask the question with what I tried to do. Sorry. 
Also, @MatthewPilling, yes you stop fishing immediately after catching the second perch.

Comment: I don't know if this is the right place to ask this, but I think peoples' confusion about my questions existing because I try to make questions shorter therefore they become more and more shallow. But at the same I don't want people to invest their time in a question they might rather don't want to explain. I wonder what can I do about this. Thanks.

Comment: I think anybody whose seriously pursued and studied mathematics has felt what you're feeling. Hang it there

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Hint

P(Perch) $= \frac{1}{2}$

P(not a Perch) $= \frac{1}{2}$

Use Negative Binomial theorem $P(X=x/r,p) = {x-1\choose r-1} p^{r}(1-p)^{x-r}$

P(X = x=4/r=2,p) $= {3\choose1}(\frac{1}{2})^2(\frac{1}{2})^2$ $= \frac{3}{16}$

Comment: The question does not ask for "2 perches among 4 fish caught", but rather "4 fish in total upon catching a second perch".

Comment: Got it, changed the solution